# How to solve this nonlinear second- order ODE?

Tags: differential-equations

Any help how in Mathematica to solve

`y’’[t]+1/2 y’[t]^2 - 1/2 Exp[y[t]]+2 ==0`

To get y(t), with no knowledge by any initial conditions for y(t) or y’(t) ?

Edit: I’m making these solutions to reach for initial constraints on y[t] , like y[0], or y’[0] at arbitrary integration constants values.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please at least write the equation in Mathematica syntax.

Comment: Related: [(195654)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/195654)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92692/discussion-on-question-by-s-s-how-to-solve-this-nonlinear-second-order-ode).

Comment: @Kuba, please I want to report replies from one of the members  here ( Michael E2) on this thread: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/207479/how-to-solve-a-couple-of-equations-with-a-constraint-by-ndsolve .  His replies are offensive, not polit, and not helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the parametric function

```
eq = y''[t] + 1/2 y'[t]^2 - 1/2 Exp[y[t]] + 2 == 0;
ic = {y[0] == a, y'[0] == b};
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq, ic}, y, {t, 0, 1}, {a, b}]

Table[Plot[Evaluate[Table[sol[a, b][t], {a, -1, 1, 0.5}]], {t, 0, 1}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "y"}, PlotLabel -> Row[{"b = ", b}], 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic], {b, -1, 1, 1}]
```

[image: fig1]